# Corona sprite.timeScale resets animation to start

Tags: sprite, coronasdk

How can I increase the animation speed in Corona? Changing the `sprite.timeScale` property makes the animation restart.

Comment: For one thing, StackOverflow isn't a forum. There's a search bar in the upper right corner. Alternatively, just search via Google.

Comment: Okay, I asked around and I have some questions to ask you:When you change the sprite timeScale, are you doing anything in addition, like change the animation sequence? I just tested the timeScale operation and it works as expected... does not reset the animation to frame 1. Which build of Corona are you using?

Comment: Hi Rob,I was using 2012.971 (2012.11.15). I am not doing anything else. The timescale is reset very frequently, it was on every frame, I put a filter now that does it only once every second or so, but still it has some issues.

Comment: @phant0m I did try to search first with no luck. That is why I came to stackoverflow. I though it was designed exactly for this type of specific issues, weather is a programming language or a framework like, jqwery, Xcode, Corona or any other. Please let me know if I miss interpreted the posting guidelines, maybe I misunderstood them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer for the first question, but for the 2nd ones, we know the forum search is borked and we are in the process of fixing it, but in the mean time, your best search results come from Google.  Do your google search like:

```
site:coronalabs.com magic formula
```

and that will give you the best search results until the problem gets solved.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I will give that a shot. It's a pity as the forum search was for me the most useful part of having a community. It seems that it has been that way for quite some time now.